# acquire lease on azure blob for timeperiod returns null

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

We are trying acquire a lease on a blob by calling Microsoft Azure Blob Java api for a period of 300seconds. But the API always returns null. Has anybody faced this issue? Below is the code that we use.

```
public void String getBlobLeaseId(com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob blob) {
    String leaseId = blob.acquireLease(300, null);
    System.out.println(leaseId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually surprised that you didn't get any error because you're specifying incorrect value for the lease duration. For infinite lease, the lease duration should be specified as `-1` and for finite lease, the lease duration value should be between `15 - 60` seconds.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob

Comment: Hi @Gaurav, Thanks for the link. We are processing a file which will take 5 or 10mns. We don't want infinite lease since the file can reprocessed by another node if something goes wrong. But now I see the maximum lease time is only 60s. Please let me know if there is any other option for this ?